# How can I get raster layers to display when I switch to them, even if the zoom is too high for them?

Tags: openlayers, zoom

I am using OpenLayers 3.15 and have an application that mostly does what I want it to do. However I do have a little issue with displaying some layers when I first switch to them.

You can see it if you go to http://mapping4ops.org/ShowMapsDev/M4OPS-index.html?OPS=HcN&Layer1=No%20layer, and zoom in 4 times. Now switch the base layer to eg Bartholemew, 1897-1907, and that layer does not display. I presume it is something to do with maxResolution and maxZoom for the layer, but I do not really understand these.

If you now zoom out 4 times, the layer displays, and if you zoom back in 4 times the layer remains displayed (fuzzily). I would like the layer to display when you first switch to it, even though it is fuzzy.

To do the switch in js I am using:

```
thismap.getLayers().removeAt(layerindex);
thismap.getLayers().insertAt(layerindex,layer);
```

I get the same problem with all of my raster layers (some served by tileserver on my own server, and others from geo.nls.uk), when the map is at too high a zoom level. They all appear when I zoom out enough and then remain when I zoom back in.

I have considered various ways to force the layer to display when I first switch to it, but not found one that works. I see applications that do not seem to have this problem, so how do I solve this?